# How to continue a Quiz game if it is stopped at any point in android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am creating a multiple choice quiz game where there is an option to continue the game from where the user has left. Example, if user stopped the application at Question Number 4, then by pressing the continue option will resume the quiz game from Question Number 4 itself. I am not able to understand how should I move ahead by coding way? What is the right way to continue a multiple choice quiz game? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could save their game state to a text file. Perhaps XML as a clean way of formatting their answers, current question, etc.

Comment: Hi @adchilds, Can you please give me an example so that I can better understand?

Comment: Does the below answer help give you a better understanding of how to use XML? Try visiting the link in the answer and googling around for help with JDOM. I feel that JDOM is a very easy library to use to interface with XML files. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you could use [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org). Just include the .jar file in your projects build path and then you'll have access to the JDOM library methods.

An example of using the JDOM libraries:

```
// Create a new XML document in memory
Document doc = new Document();
Element root = new Element("child");
doc.setRootElement(root); // set ^ above element as the root element

root.addContent(new Element( "childname" )); // add a data element to the root

root.getChild("childname").setText("SOME INFO"); // give some data to the element <childname>

// Save the XML file
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("FILENAME.xml");
XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
outputter.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat()); // sets correct tabbing/format in the file
outputter.output(doc, writer);
```

This would make something like:

```
<child>
    <childname>SOME INFO</childname>
</child>
```

You can then access the information stored in the XML file by using some JDOM methods like:

```
root.getChild("SOME CHILD").getText();
```

Of course JDOM isn't the only option here. It's whatever seems easiest for you, not me.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting your questions from? Try to build a sqlite db around your game. Get your questions from there. Then when the player goes out save state of the quiz in a db table, and when he comes back resume the game. Also you can store his previous performances, current performance in seperate tables. Seems like a good way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple solution actually. A sql read will always result in the same sequence of read when you make a select call. So if you have 100 rows, and you select 10 rows of them and choose the first one, it will always be the same. Practically tested and it works. Now, you can create a "played" flag in your table and flag your quiz played. This way you will always get the same question in the same sequence as you reset.

If you want to randomize, I suggest you code that. There is no automatic way to do it.

Now for question, you should use shared preferences to save current question being played. This way you can just read that one row when you restart your application.